# D3.js: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've just [downloaded D3.js from d3js.org](http://d3js.org/d3.v3.zip) (link to zip file), unzipped it, and referenced it in the following HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>D3 Sandbox</title>
<style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/d3.v3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I load this page, my console (in Chrome) is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL: line 2
```

It doesn't like the [pi and e symbols at the start of the file](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.js#L2). Errrr... what can I do about this? I am serving the file with python's SimpleHTTPServer.

Update: yes I know I can just link to a CDN version, but I would prefer to serve the file locally.

Comment: the problem for me was that simplehttpserver doesn't support utf8 per default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288891/how-can-i-serve-files-with-utf-8-encoding-using-python-simplehttpserver

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Try specifying the UTF-8 charset on the HTML host document :

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">`

D3 contains UTF-8 symbols (like π) invalids in non-UTF8 documents.

Comment: <meta charset="UTF8"> did the trick for me,
for some reason the longer version didn't. thanks

Comment: Can you comment on why this is necessary?

Comment: BBischof : D3 contains UTF-8 symbols (like π) invalids in non-UTF8 documents

Comment: This doesn't help if the user has their View->Encoding setting off of Auto-Detect in Chrome. Running it through uglify with the --ascii-only option is more reliable.

Comment: I have the same issue in WebFocus, but it didn't correct the error for me.  I had to go with the d3.min.js instead.

Comment: You need to use UTF8 because D3 you some character like π (Pi) : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1195

Answer (score 9):

That sounds like a problem with encoding. I recommend [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Despite the somewhat condescending title, it contains some very useful information. Specifically, it sounds like your server is serving the `d3.v3.js` file with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 6):

Add 'charset="utf-8"'

```
<script src="/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Lame though it is, this doesn't help if the user has their View->Encoding setting off of Auto-Detect in Chrome. Running it through uglify with the --ascii-only option is more reliable.

Answer (score 5):

I tried setting the charset in the doc and in the script tag itself, but Chrome doesn't seem to care. Not sure if i'm doing something wrong.

I did find success by running it through uglify with the --ascii-only option first.

UPDATE: Turns out my View->Encoding setting in Chrome was not on Auto-Detect, but some Western encoding. Not sure why, but changing that resolved the problem. Ridiculous that that setting would trump a charset property right on the script tag. Considering that users might be in the same situation and not be able to figure it out, i'll still be using uglify to ensure success.

Comment: had the same problem. Changing the encoding setting to auto-detect fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a plus sign between all of your string concatenations, if you do not this error will be generated.