# How can I serve files with UTF-8 encoding using Python SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, webserver

I often use the following to quickly fire up a web server to serve HTML content from the current folder (for local testing):

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Is there a reasonably simple way I can do this, but have the server serve the files with a UTF-8 encoding rather than the system default?

Comment: is the encoding changed by SimpleHTTPServer?  Being simple I would assume it serves the bytes as is.

Comment: You are right: it wasn't the file encoding, I was missing the charset meta tag in the HTML. Thanks for getting me on the right track!

Comment: Not quite sure what to do with this question now though—delete it?

Comment: I'd leave it. If a mod disagrees, he/she will show up.

Comment: well, same problem here, charset is utf-8. And still not working.

Comment: setting meta tag worked for me, earlier UTF emojis were shown as garbage text

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Had the same problem, the following code worked for me.

To start a SimpleHTTPServer with UTF-8 encoding, simply copy/paste the following in terminal (for Python 2).

```
python -c "import SimpleHTTPServer; m = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map; m[''] = 'text/plain'; m.update(dict([(k, v + ';charset=UTF-8') for k, v in m.items()])); SimpleHTTPServer.test();"
```

Ensure that you have the correct charset in your HTML files beforehand.

**EDIT**: Update for Python 3:

```
python3 -c "from http.server import test, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler as RH; RH.extensions_map={k:v+';charset=UTF-8' for k,v in RH.extensions_map.items()}; test(RH)"
```

The `test` function also accepts arguments like `port` and `bind` so that it's possible to specify the address and the port to listen on.

Comment: In this example, how do I change the server port?

Comment: @Gurzo Just append the portnumber as an argument to the python command. Like `python -c "import ..." 1234` to run it on port 1234.

Comment: I had the same problem. Couldn't get the code working, but adding <meta charset="utf-8" /> fixed the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it with Python scripts too.

```py
from functools import partial
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test
import os

print('http://localhost:8000/')
wk_dir = os.getcwd()
SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map = {k: v + ';charset=UTF-8' for k, v in SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map.items()}
test(HandlerClass=partial(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, directory=wk_dir), port=8000, bind='')
```

---

Since `test` is not in `http.server.__all__` so IDE may show a warning, and if you don't want to see it, you can use `importlib` instead of it. for example:

```py
import importlib
http_server = importlib.import_module('http.server')
http_server.test(HandlerClass=partial(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, directory=wk_dir), port=8000, bind='')
```